# Flask, jinja2 - Dynamically append templates one after another

Tags: html, templates, flask, jinja2, python-3.6

I am building a chatbot. There are few child templates like login.html, messages.html, transaction.html, etc. I want to append these templates in base.html dynamically. I am extending base.html in all these templates. My problem is only one template is rendered at a time. Is there any solution for appending these templates one after another? I have used {%include%} but it's a static approach. I need dynamic.

printer.py looks like -

```
@app.route('/respond', methods=['GET','POST'])
def respond_def():
   message = request.form['message_input']
   if message == "l":
       return render_template('printer/login.html')
   elif message == "t":
       return render_template('printer/transactionID.html')
```

base.html looks like -

```
//some code here
<li>
    {% block template %}{% endblock %}
</li>
//some code here
```

message.html looks like -

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block template %}
<div> Message template called </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.
I made a list of templates in printer.py and then appended those templates in base.html whenever user asked for it.

printer.py

```
dictionary = []
// append name of template in this whenever needed.
return render_template('printer/base.html', dictionary=dictionary)
```

base.html

```
{% for d in dicts %}
{% set template = 'printer/' + d + '.html' %}
// can add conditions for different templates
{% include template %}
{% endfor %}
```